# PHP how to check current DateTime and future DateTime until difference becomes 0

Tags: php, datetime

Is it possible to check current DateTime and future DateTime in every 30 seconds until difference becomes 0 ( current DateTime to be equal to the future DateTime ) with precision of a minute using PHP ?
My code is not continuously in every 30 seconds:

```
<?php
  $dt_format = 'Y-m-d H:i';

  $new_row = "<br>";

  $dt_now = new DateTime();
  $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat($dt_format, '2016-09-01 14:00');
  $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat($dt_format, '2016-09-01 14:15');

  print("Today is " . $dt_now->format($dt_format) . $new_row);

  $diff1 = $dt_now->diff($date1);
  print ($diff1->format('%y years %m months %d days %h hours %i minutes') . $new_row);

  $diff2 = $dt_now->diff($date2);
  print ($diff2->format('%y years %m months %d days %h hours %i minutes') . $new_row);
?>
```

Comment: Um what? I believe that would create a paradox.

Comment: @cmorrissey Great Scott!

Comment: I believe what they are asking is can they set a future date/time in a variable and have php check every 30 seconds (cron or similar) to see if the current time is equal to that variable date/time. Likely to trigger some sort of action.

Comment: what are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you want to block the page load into the time matches? That will lead to resource exhaustion on your server if the target time is too long.

PHP is single threaded so you can't do this check in the background.

Better to write out a holding page for the user, which tries to reload every 30 seconds.

If the time is reached, show the content, otherwise show a page with this content:

```
<p>Please wait until (put target time)</p>
<script>
     setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.reload();
     }, 30000);
</script>
```